# Remove "Server" header in ADFS 3.0

Tags: security, server, header, adfs, adfs3.0

For security purposes we want te remove the "Server" header from all our websites. However, we have not been successful with our ADFS 3.0 website. We have already tried to remove it using the "DisableServerHeader" reg key:

[View a screenshot of the reg key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGM1E.png)

We have applied this on the following servers:

- ADFS server
- The server running the Web Application Proxy
- The server running the ASP.NET web site

In succession, we rebooted the servers. In addition, we have added the following code to our ASP.NET website in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;
    application?.Context?.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

[View a screenshot of the response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZTSv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADFS 3.0 doesn't run on IIS and ADFS in general has no facility to manipulate headers.

The only way to do this is to put a proxy in front of ADFS and do it there.